# jsGrid not loading Spring-boot json

Tags: spring, rest, jsgrid

Restfull api returns json fine.  Trying to use the json data to populate a jsGrid on a html page.  Must be doing something wrong fundamentally as all example I have found fail.  What i see are the column names with 'Not found' written as only row.

Any ideas?

This still giving me "Not Found":

```
    controller: {
            loadData: function(filter) {
            return {
                      data: [{"Name":"Edmund","Age": "25"},
                             {"Name":"Edmund","Age": "25"}
                            ],
                      itemsCount: 2
                  };
            }
        },

    fields: [
        { name: "Name", type: "text", width: 150 },
        { name: "Age", type: "text", width: 50 }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsGrid expects the data in the following format.

```
{"data":[...],"itemsCount":<data count>}
```

Initially, I had the same problem. So, I first tried sending a hard-coded string from controller as below

```
String responseStr = "{\"data\":[{\"fld_1\": \"val1\",\"fld_2\": \"val2\"},{\"fld_1\": \"val3\",\"fld_2\": \"val4\"],\"itemsCount\":2}";
```

It worked. Now, we use some data object as below

```
public class MyDataDO {
    private List<Map<String, Object>> data;
    private int itemsCount;
    //setter/getter
}
```

Also, can you make sure that you have set the `autoload` to a correct value?

**EDIT:**

you can do it as below

```
...
controller: {
                loadData: function(filter) {
                return {
                          data: [{"field_1":"val1","field_2": "val2"},
                                 {"field_1":"val3","field_2": "val4"}
                                ],
                          itemsCount: 2
                      };
                }
            }
```

The following page appears fine. All the js and css files are from the distribution that comes with jsgrid.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demos.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/jsgrid.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/theme.css" />
    <script src="../external/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/jsgrid.core.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/jsgrid.load-indicator.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/jsgrid.load-strategies.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/jsgrid.sort-strategies.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/jsgrid.field.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="jsGrid"></div>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
                pageLoading : true,
                autoload: true,
                controller: {
                    loadData: function(filter) {
                        return {
                            data: [
                                    {"Name":"Edmund","Age": "25"},
                                    {"Name":"Edmund","Age": "25"}
                            ],
                            itemsCount: 2
                        };
                    },

                  },
                  fields: [
                    { name: "Name", type: "text", width: 100 },
                    { name: "Age", type: "text", width:150}
                ]

            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cheers for this.
Do you know whet the json should look like if I want to directly attach it for testing purposes to the javascript jsGrid declaration.  

i.e. controller: function()...

Comment: Cheers.  Can you see my edited question... I added the sample, I think it is correct?  Still getting 'not found' although i see tale columns.

Comment: Will try to set this up later today.